# Java - Returning multiple values from loop, as single string

Tags: java, string, loops, int, return

I have a method where I pass two int arguments, and returns a string. A loop will make sure that if the first argument(the greater value) is greater than the second, that the first will decrement until it is equal the value of the second argument(the lesser value).
The problem I'm having is that I am trying to return the value of the decremented value after each time that the loop runs. I would like to return the values as a string like "8,6,4,2".How would i set that up?

```
 public String countDown(int arg1, int arg2){
    if (arg1>arg2){
        for (int i = arg1; arg1>arg2;i--){
            //???

            return i;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please, Please, Please do not do this. Return an `int[]` or `List<int>`.

Comment: That loop is going to run forever if you remove the `return` from it, or else it's going to exit the first time through if it has the `return` in it. Either way, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your `return` outside the loop.

And you need to declare an object before the loop, in which store the values as you encounter them, before finally returning it at the end.

```
 String out = "";
 for(int i = arg1; i>arg2; i--) {
     out = out + i + ",";
 }
 return out;
```

This has a couple of issues:

- There is always an extra "," at the end of the returned String
- Although it might be a good enough solution to your homework problem, returning a String from a method like this isn't usually the best design. It would be better to return, for example, a List of integers, because that's a structure that retains the actual "meaning" of the data more than a String does in this case.

You can find help with both of those by searching on this site (there is no need to ask another question) - or by reading ahead in your Java textbook.

Comment: You can eliminate the trailing comma by conditionally appending it `if (i > arg2+1)` and you can improve things greatly by creating a StringBuilder. Otherwise, Java is going to create a new StringBuilder every time around the loop.

Comment: @DavidConrad Eliminating comma: yes, but I hoped to goad OP into working that out for himself. StringBuilder: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuilder:

```
public String countDown(int arg1, int arg2){
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (arg1>arg2){
        for (int i = arg1; arg1>arg2;i--){
            //???
            stringBuilder.append(/*whatever*/);
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();

}
```